# Is there any way to place the Ebony Blade on a rack?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a lovely display of Daedric artefacts in the basement of my house in Solitude.  Irritatingly, the Ebony Blade refuses to be held by any weapon rack (whether wall mounted or free standing).  It is unequipped successfully but then falls onto the floor rather than being attached to the mount.

I had thought that this was just a sign that two handed weapons can't be mounted, however there were iron greatswords pre-supplied in them and further research has revealed that this is a known bug with the Ebony Blade.  *Has anyone found a method of mounting the ebony blade*?

Answer (score 6):

According to TES wiki:

> This weapon ( like some other Daedric Artifacts ) has an unstable physical model which causes it to disappear, delete, move, and fall when placed on weapons plaques, weapons racks, and in the world in general. Exercise **caution** when placing in a home. However it is not affected when placed in a storage container or while in inventory. PS3 PC 360

I know when I tried to place mine in a weapons case it disappeared and I had to leave and re-enter my home multiple times for it to regenerate on the floor. So I re-emphasize, **be careful**. Best option is to put it in a chest, though I know its pretty and you want to show it off.

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ebony_Blade_(Skyrim)

(Once on page - scroll to bugs, this is main bullet point 7 on the list for the weapon.)

Comment: Could you link to the source?

Comment: @galacticninja Theres the source for you, hope it helps, has assisted me more than once.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug and has been noted at the [UESP Wiki's "Ebony Blade" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ebony_Blade#Bugs) and has been [reported in the Unofficial Skyrim Patch's bug tracker](http://afkmods.iguanadons.net/index.php?/tracdown/issue/193-ebony-blade-will-not-stick-to-a-weapon-rack-when-used/).

> - Both versions of the Ebony Blade can be placed upon a weapon rack, but *neither will stay there*. This may result in the loss of the blade when it falls off into unreachable areas.
> - The daedric artifact Ebony Blade will not stay put on any weapon rack it's displayed on. When you come back to the house after being gone, it will be on the floor below the rack.

And according to the comments in the USKP bug report, the mod, **[Weapon Display FIX](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/27374)** fixes that issue for the Ebony Blade.

> As you may know many vanilla and modded weapons are not positioning on racks/plaques when you try to do that.
>   This mod is an workaround, hopefully temporary till Beth fixes the root issue.
>
> Vanilla script was edited and not replaced in order to keep the script variables that changed during gameplay.

Answer (score 2):

A friend and I have been experimenting with this, and to date, we have not been able to get the ebony blade to mount on a weapon rack, no matter what.

For reference, we are playing on the 360, both of us.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you can. I believe it is just a bug.

There might be a mod available that enables you to do this however.

Comment: With Decorator Assistant you can put objects anywhere and then lock them in place, so there's at least one mod that can do it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (if you can call it that) is to use a display case, but rather than activating the display case, drop the weapon and drag it into the case manually, then close the case. This is the only way I found that works on Xbox 1/Xbox 360

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to attempt to put The Ebony Blade on a rack don't leave the house afterwards; load instead from the last auto save. It's much simpler and much safer.

I've never found a way to place it on the rack myself, though.

Comment: I guess there's a down-vote because I'm sure he did this many times and maybe was a reloading saves.

Answer (score -1):

I struggled with this for a long time, and the only way to get The ebony Blade to stay on display is to find a display case, open it, and then drop the Blade from your inventory and then manually drag it to where it fits in the case, however, it will slide out if you do not close the case when you're done. Works for me.